# 抜けている文字を返すアルゴリズムの問題について

Tags: javascript

下記リンク先のアルゴリズムの問題に取り組んでいるのですが、私の作ったコードではエラーになってしまい、理由がわからないため質問させていただきます。

[Intermediate Algorithm Scripting: Missing letters - freeCodeCamp.org](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/missing-letters)

以下のように動作するコードを作りたいです。
（抜けている文字を返す）

```
myFunction("abce")             //return "d".
myFunction("stvwx")            //return "u".
myFunction("bcdf")             //return "e".
myFunction("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")   //return  undefined.(a~zまで揃っている場合はundefined）
```

以下が、私の作ったコードです。

```
function myFunction(str) {
  for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    return str.charCodeAt(i)!==str.charCodeAt(i+1)-1
    ? String.fromCharCode(i+1)
    : undefined;
  }
}
```

どこに不備があるか、どなたかご指摘いただけないでしょうか。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「どこに不備があるか、どなたかご指摘いただけないでしょうか。」とのことなので、ざっと不備のある点を指摘していきます。

出題自体には色々なやり方が考えられますが、できるだけ現在のあなたのコードが活かせるという観点でチェックしています。

- forループの中で必ずreturnしている
  returnするのは、「抜けている文字」が見つかったときだけのはずです。undefinedを返すのは、最後までチェックして「抜けている文字」が見つからなかったときですから、根本的にロジックがおかしいです。ざっくりと、

  ```
    for( ... ) {
      if( 抜けている文字がある ) {
        return 抜けている文字
      }
    }
    //「抜けている文字」が見つからなかったとき
    return undefined;
  ```

  と言う感じになるはずです。
- for文の範囲がまずい
  「抜けている文字」のチェックの中で`str.charCodeAt(i+1)`を参照しているのに、`for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){`と文字列の最初から最後までループを回しています。これでは、上記の修正をしても、`i`が文字列の最後に来たときに、`str.charCodeAt(i+1)`が範囲外をアクセスすることになるので、実行時エラーになります。現在のチェックの式を使うならループの範囲は文字列の最後の位置より1個手前までにしないといけません。
- 文字列の位置を文字コードとして返そうとしている
  `String.fromCharCode(i+1)`という部分がありますが、この中で`i+1`は、「`str`の中で今調べている場所の次の場所」を表す整数値であって、文字コードではありません。「抜けている文字」が見つかった場合には、`String.fromCharCode(「抜けている文字」の文字コード)`を返してやらないといけません。

わかりにくい点があれば、コメント等でお知らせください。

Answer (score 0):

return すると for の中であろうと関係なく function から抜け出してしまいます。つまり質問者さんのコードでは for ループの繰り返しの最初の 1 回で終了してしまいます。

「最初から最後まで条件を満たしているかどうかチェックしつつ、満たしていなかったらその場で return し、最後まで満たしていればループを抜けた後に return する」ような形に書き換えてみてください。

Answer (score 0):

こちらでうまく動きました。

https://jsbin.com/vuvabazidu/1/edit?html,js,console

```
function myFunction(str) {
  for(var i=0; i<str.length - 1; i++){
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) !== str.charCodeAt(i+1) - 1) {
      return String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i) + 1);
    }
  }
}

console.log(myFunction("abce"))
console.log(myFunction("stvwx"))
console.log(myFunction("bcdf"))
console.log(myFunction("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
```

結果
"d"
"u"
"e"
undefined